# Chai-http not working

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

Getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
      at Immediate. (node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:14)

Server and test files.

```
// server js file
'use strict';

var express = require('express');        // call express
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Routes for schedule API
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({"msg":'Hello, World!'});
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Application running on port ' + port);

module.exports=router;

// test.js 
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp=require('chai-http');

var server = require('../server');
var should = chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);
describe('Scheduler', function () {            
    it('should return hello world', function (done) {
        chai.request(server)
            .get('/')
            .end(function (err, res) {
                res.should.have.status(200);
                done();
            };
    });
});
```

Could anybody help me to track what went wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use expect instead of should it's more easier

```
var chai = require('chai'), chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
chai.use(chaiHttp);
var expect = chai.expect;
app.get('/check', function(req, res) {
//exemple
expect(req.query.ip,"IP Adress Mismatch").to.be.an.ip;
}
```

Comment: getting error from express...so i believe switch to expect won't fix this.

Comment: If you remove from //test.js and the code after do you get errors?

Comment: check this your code it seems fine to work  but var server = require('../server'); maybe not found

Comment: if i put log stmt                                                                                   router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {                                   console.log("here");
res.json({"msg":'Hello, World!'});                                                                         }); getting that here msg as well

Comment: and if I return promise from get method i would get an error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: res.json is not a function.

Comment: Use res.send intead of json

Comment: already tried but didn't work..getting error ends with TypeError: res.send is not a function

Comment: So try to change your chai method you there are many differents methods